# How to make TidFTPServer working with SSL

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10

I m looking for example but can't find one working. How can i make `TidFTPServer` accepting SSL connection (password and data encrypted) ? I understand that i need to use `IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` but I can't make it working

This is the code i did :

```
fIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(nil);
fIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [TIdSSLVersion.sslvSSLv2, TIdSSLVersion.sslvSSLv23, TIdSSLVersion.sslvSSLv3, TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1, TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_1, TIdSSLVersion.sslvTLSv1_2];
fFTPServer.IOHandler := fIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
```

I have the error in the ftp server:

> TIDFtpServer: Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with
>   message 'Error accepting connection with SSL. error:1408A0C1:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher

Comment: The difference between the two should be very clear. Just like all other Indy components, the ones with `Server` are for the server-side, while the other is for the client-side.

Comment: thanks @JerryDodge, so i get it :) now just need to know how to use it with TIDFtpServer ...

Comment: The very first search result on Google (after this one): http://www.indyproject.org/kb/index.html?howdoiuseftpwithssl.htm

Comment: @JerryDodge beat me to it, I was unaware of that doc and was just writing up similar instructions

Comment: @RemyLebeau no please remy continue writing! I read this doc but it's not explain if we need to create a certificate, if yes how to create it, do we need to implement the getpassword of the TIdServerIOHandlerSSL, do need openSLL dll (where to get it), etc.

Comment: @loki What I had written is already mentioned in the doc. As its name implies, `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` uses OpenSSL, so yes, you need the OpenSSL DLLs (you can get them from [Indy's Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/)). A certificate is not STRICTLY REQUIRED but it is STRONGLY RECOMMENDED for a server (especially if clients are configured to fail if no server certificate is present), but getting a certificate is outside the scope of Indy. There are many providers available, shop around. You don't need the `OnGetPassword/Ex` event(s) unless your certificate is password-protected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks remy, so i try exactly like written in the doc, don't set a certificate, and i receive in the ftp server using TIDFtpServer: Exception class EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message
'Error accepting connection with SSL.
error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher'. on the client i use total commander with SSL

Comment: @loki did you make sure that client and server are both configured to enable the same SSL/TLS version(s)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hmm on client i use well know Total commander (their only only one option: use SSL/TLS). on the server i didn't touch anything, i just do fIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(nil); fFTPServer.IOHandler := fIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174750/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-loki).